# gflags does not flag any binary

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-7, gflags

I'm trying to run `gflags` x64 on my `Release x64` binary built by `Visual Studio 2013` to detect access violations.
I downloaded Windows Debugging Tools from Microsoft website.
I added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64` to my `PATH` environment variable, `gflags` and `windbg` are found in Windows prompt.

**Edit: Added already tried commands**

I tried to flag with following commands:
`gflags /p /enable D:\MyBinary.exe /full /protect`
`gflags /p /enable D:\MyBinary.exe`
`gflags /p /enable MyBinary.exe /full /protect`
`gflags /p /enable -i MyBinary.exe /full /protect`
`gflags /p /enable /i MyBinary.exe /full /protect`
`gflags -p -enable -i MyBinary.exe -full -protect`

then I want to check if binary is properly flagged with
`gflags /p`

`MyBinary.exe` is not listed, `gflags /p` displays nothing.

I retried by disabling `UAC` to see if it's different, no better result.
I also tried to flag another binary (notepad++.exe), still no flagging.

What's wrong with my commands ?

Comment: Try without the path `gflags /p /enable MyBinary.exe /full /protect` also shouldn't you be using `-i` to specify the imageFileName? `gflags /p /enable -i MyBinary.exe /full /protect`?

Comment: Just tried `gflags /p /enable MyBinary.exe /full /protect` and `gflags /p /enable -i MyBinary.exe /full /protect`, still no result in `gflags /p`

Comment: you may have better joy using the gui version of gflags by double-clicking this in the debuggers folder and then toggling the flags and entering the app name on the Image File tab

Comment: I also tried with `/i` instead of `-i`, `gflags /p /enable /i MyBinary.exe /full /protect`, still does not work.

Comment: @EdChum, actually I really need to execute gflags in command line, it's part of daily tests in Jenkins.

Comment: I don't have the windows 10 version installed but the 8.1 SDK version shows that the flags are passed using `-` rather than `/` can you try substituting `/` for `-` and see if it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96016/discussion-between-leflou-and-edchum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an Administrator prompt, this command is working:
`D:\>gflags /p /enable MyBinary.exe /full /protect
path: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options
    mybinary.exe: page heap enabled`